# Перенос строки в java

Tags: google-maps, android, java

Пишу приложение для android, вставил гугл карты, но ни как не могу понять, как делать перенос строки, ни `\n \n\r \\n` - ничего не помогает, на карте всё равно всё пишется в одну строчку. Как сделать перенос наподобие `<br>`?

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(59.961159, 30.291961)).title("Название точки").snippet("Станция метро \"Чкаловская\", Устройство расположено в вестибюле станции метро рядом со входом.\n" +
    "Часы работы\n" +
    "\n" +
    "Пн-Вс: 6:00 - 0:00")  );
```

**Обновление**

Спасибо, но он почему-то у вас ругается на xml файл, по идее же должно быть так?

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="com.example.client6.tetrapolis.MapsActivity2"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

И дальше ваш xml

```
Error:(9) Error parsing XML: junk after document element
```

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо сделать кастомное информационное окно

```
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new Yourcustominfowindowadpater());

class Yourcustominfowindowadpater implements InfoWindowAdapter {
        private final View mymarkerview;

        Yourcustominfowindowadpater() {
            mymarkerview = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.view_info_window, null);
    }

    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        render(marker, mymarkerview);
        ((TextView) mymarkerview.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker
                .getTitle());
        ((TextView) mymarkerview.findViewById(R.id.snippet)).setText(marker
                .getSnippet());
        return mymarkerview;
    }

    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        ((TextView) mymarkerview.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker
                .getTitle());
        ((TextView) mymarkerview.findViewById(R.id.snippet)).setText(marker
                .getSnippet());
        return null;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
    }
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_white">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но он почему то у вас ругается на xml файл, по идее же должно быть так?
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.client6.tetrapolis.MapsActivity2"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
И дальше ваш xml
Error:(9) Error parsing XML: junk after document element

Comment: Вы добавили в мой xml карту? Тот xml, который скинул я, описывает только информационное окно, всплывающее при клике на маркер. Сам фрагмент с картой должен быть в отдельном xml файле.

Comment: Гм, а как их соединить? Это всё маркеры для карты.

Comment: Свой код оставьте как есть, в папке layout создайте файл view_info_window. В него скопируйте мою разметку.

Comment: и код java и xml?

Comment: Код java необходимо вставить в вашу активность с картами.

Comment: @Lsoldier52 Куда бы не вставил код lava, он почему-то ругается на getActivity() и предлогает создать новый класс.